# Which Type of data to use for a small project

Tags: .net, xml, database, data-structures

I have a personnal project. In your opinion, which type of data structure I should use (text file, xml, other) ?

Here are the main points of my project :
- Can't really use any database server since it's for a personnal use and I don't want to install anything else than the software itself;
- I got a small numbers of object class which I will need to store (15 max);
- If it makes any differences, I will use WPF to design the interface.

I was thinking about using XML files. I could use XMLSerialiser for that but I don't really know a lot about those
I also though about a mdb database but since the driver for mdb file is not longer designed in 64bit (or so I heard), I don't think I can really use it since I believe accdb file requires the installation of a driver into each computer I will install and I don't want that. If not, then I guess accdb would be my second choice.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you consider using something like SQL Server Compact. This will allow you to package a small database file along with your application and you wont need to install anything extra.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

Comment: Forgot about but this is nice idea. Is it supported by .NET nativly ?

Comment: You will need to distribute the library with your application. You get most of the usual functionality of SQL Server with a few limitations. Obviously performance is not as good as SQL Server, but for a project that doesn't use huge amounts of data and complex SQL queries, performance will be good.

Comment: By Distribute the libraray I guess you only mean include the necessary dll in the project folder like any dll in a .net project ?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without more information, but [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a small fast SQL database that doesn't require any software to be installed. .NET support is provided by [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

I've used this software in a small project before, and it worked very well for me.

Comment: Didn't think of either SQLLite or SQLCompact... Can you tell me about it ? What does it support ?

Comment: SQLite is a very high-quality self-contained public-domain SQL database engine that uses a single, cross-platform normal file for storage. You can store just about anything in it, and the whole system takes about 300KB of memory. More features here: http://sqlite.org/features.html